# How to define shared constant on Elixir

Tags: elixir

Can I define constant shared with modules?

Generally, we use module attribute for constant inside module.
http://elixir-lang.github.io/getting-started/module-attributes.html#as-constants

If I want to make constant available to other modules, how can I do it?
At first, module attribute is available just only inside module(1).
I know I can use function as constant(2).
But if possible, I want to define constant by dedicated form like 3.

```
defmodule Sample do
    # 1. module attribute(available only inside module)
    @private_const_value 1
    # 2. function as constant(possible in any rate)
    def const_value_func, do: 3
    # 3. ideal form(but compile error)
    public_const_value = 2
end

defmodule Client do
    def foo() do
        IO.puts "CONST = #{Sample.@private_const_value}" # compile error
        IO.puts "CONST = #{Sample.const_value_func}"
        IO.puts "CONST = #{Sample.public_const_value}" # compile error
    end
end
```

#### postscript

I expect that constant satisfies following requirements.

- evaluation at compile-time
- classification by module(I means constants should be defined at appropriate module)

Comment: I used to use config(like `Application.get_env`) to define constant shared with modules.

Comment: @YongHaoHu Your comment clarify my question. I added postscript about requirements for constant.

Comment: Short answer--no, there's no way to get the constant behavior you demonstrate on option #3 above.  The other thing is that Elixir is case sensitive about value names so using ALL_CAPS presents other issues.

Comment: @OnorioCatenacci As you say, uppercase variable cause misleading to another discussion. I changed the name from uppercase to lowercase.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A non-module-specific constant is generally put in `config/foo.exs`, and accessed by `System.get_env/1` or `Application.get_env/2`. If you want it to be under/inside a specific module (and not just a specific application) for reasons that can't be satisfied by just giving it an appropriate name and using one of the above options... first, be sure that that's accurate and you have a good reason, because I can't think of one off the top of my head.

If you still want that, the answer is (AFAIK) just your option-2, the function. If you want a dedicated form for it, do it with a macro:

```
defmacro const([{name, val}]) do
  quote do
    def unquote(name) do: unquote(val)
  end
end
```

Then you can just do `const foo: 87` in any module where you've required and imported the module with `const` defined in it.

Or you could define each constant as a macro instead of a function. Disadvantage: You need to `require` the modules. Advantage: Resolves at compile-time, like attributes do. Though functions of arity 0 that don't have side effects might do that anyway, I'm not sure but it's a reasonable optimization.

Comment: As you say, I want compile-time resolve.
At the beginning, I'll use function through const macro as constant with expecting optimization.

Comment: The syntax should be `def unquote(name)(), do: unquote(val)`. I tried editing the answer but was not allowed because the diff needed to be at least 6 characters.

Answer (score 0):

You also want to take a look at the [Module.register_attribute](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Module.html#register_attribute/3) function.  You'd use this in conjunction with [Module.get_attribute](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Module.html#get_attribute/2).  I seem to recall something about using this as a means to share attributes across modules.

Comment: Interesting. `get_attribute` is not so bad, but that's bit lengthy just for constant. So if I use that, I guess I had better wrap it in utility function or macro.